# Amazon Libs3 Issues

Tags: c++, amazon-s3

I'm trying to install a library that I can use to access Amazon's S3 service (I just need to be able to upload files there). The code needs to be in C++ because it's going to be bundled as part of an application I'm working on.

I'm trying to work with Bryan Ischo's library located here: http://libs3.ischo.com.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

I'm having some installation issues though. I changed GNUMakefile.macosx to GNUMakefile and then ran "sudo make install", as I'm developing on a Mac. Then I made a test .cpp file.

```
#include <libs3.h>
...a few other things...
int main() {
cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
S3_initialize(NULL, S3_INIT_ALL);   
return 0;
}
```

All I want to do is to be able to initialize the library, since this is what his API says to do. However, I get back this error:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_S3_initialize", referenced from:
  _main in ccRcG0yS.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

I'd like some help either fixing my installation of libs3 or getting a few tips on accessing S3 through C++.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! I am having problems with building libs3, can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test application is not linking with `libs3`. You will need to add it to the linker flags, such as `-ls3` (if the library is libs3.so/a)

Comment: Thanks! As a novice programmer myself, I'm curious: how did you know that -ls3 was the right flag?

Comment: In GCC, libraries are added to the linker command line (when invoked via the gcc/g++ driver) via the `-l` flag. The syntax is `-lname`, where `name` is the part after `lib` and before the `.so/.a`. I guessed on the library file being `libs3.so`

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem with executing a C file using Byan Ischo's library on mac and I had to add some more parameters before I was able to successfully run my test file.

How to compile libs3 on mac?

```
sudo make DESTDIR=/opt/local install
```

How to compile test.c?

```
cc test.c -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -ls3
```

How to execute a.out?

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib ./a.out
```